# Handling "this" with RequireJS and JQuery onclick events

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am updating an app to use RequireJS and move functions/variables out of the global context.  I am not sure how to structure things when using JQuery click handlers so that my functions have access to the `data-*` attributes on the HTML object that triggered the click AND have access to properties inside of my module.

Below is a simple test case I put together to demonstrate what I am trying to do.
I want a function called on the click event for the div that is able to access both the `data-value` attribute on the div that triggered it and the `packageVar` property inside the module I'm loading with RequireJS.

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Test.Next</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <script data-main="js/test-require" src="js/require.js"></script>
    <div id="test-no-bind" data-value="value">Test No Bind</div>
    <div id="test-bind" data-value="value">Test Bind</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the `test-require.js`:

```
requirejs.config({
  "baseUrl": 'js',
  "paths": {
    "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min",
    "domReady": 'vendor/domReady'
  }
});
requirejs(['maintest','domReady!'], function(main) {
  main.initialize();
});
```

And finally my `maintest.js`:

```
define(['jquery','domReady!'], function($) {
  return {
    'packageVar' : 'test',
    buttonClick : function() {
      console.log($(this).attr("data-value"));
      console.log(this.packageVar);
    },
    initialize: function() {
      $("#test-no-bind").click(this.buttonClick);
      $("#test-bind").click(this.buttonClick.bind(this));
    }
  };
});
```

The `test-no-bind` div results in:

```
value
undefined
```

The `test-bind` div results in:

```
undefined
test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a properties from two different objects using the same context `this`. So in the no-bind case you're getting correctly the `div` element value for `data-value` attribute because inside jquery `click` function the `this` context it's the element where the event is produced, however you're getting and undefined for the other object property because the element doesn't have the `packageVar` property. For bind case where you are using `bind` function you're passing your object as `this` context so you've a value for `packageVar` but not for element attribute.

Try using the correct context to call `buttonClick` and passing the element context to the function in order to get each value correctly from his source:

```
define(['jquery','domReady!'], function($) {
  return {
    'packageVar' : 'test',
    buttonClick : function(element) {
      console.log($(element).attr("data-value"));
      console.log(this.packageVar);
    },
    initialize: function() {
      var that = this;
      $("#test-no-bind").click(function() {
        that.buttonClick(this);
      });
      $("#test-bind").click(function(){
        that.buttonClick(this);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Try with this <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/albciff/oo8z77y3/9/)</kbd>

Hope this helps,